# how to create fancy button in android?

Tags: android

How to create a button as shown in the picture:

[image: button picture]

and also Image name `Button` should permanently change color on click. Moreover I will be creating this button dynamically from the android file. So it will be good if somebody suggest me in that way instead of xml files way.

Comment: file could not be seen. Kindly check.

Comment: @prem I think u need to download it. because I already given public acces to the images.

Comment: @ulidtko thanks still one more image is there.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `ImageButton` class. You can easily create this at runtime so long as you have the picture file for your button in your resources. For it to permanently change colour simply create the different coloured version of the file, put that in your resources folder too and run some code on the `onClick` of the button to change the image of the `ImageButton` to the different coloured image. Should take no more than a few lines of code.

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html